# Alert user before leaving web page with unsaved changes on form

Tags: javascript, svelte

I have forms in my application, all in one page, and I change them on button click without refreshing page.

How can I secure the form in such a way that if someone navigates away, change form or closes the browser tab, they should be prompted to to confirm they really want to leave the form with unsaved data?

Yes I know about onbeforeunload event, but it wouldn't work if I change form without refreshing page

Hope someone understand me, and can help with an advice

P.S. I work with svelte

Comment: You work with Svelte... and apparently React? Because you've added the tag for that. And there are questions with answers to your question for React.

Comment: in react also is used beforeunload, but I didn't find anything about the case then we don't refresh page. If you found some information about my case,  i will be very grateful if you can send it to me.

Comment: [`beforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event) is a native event that has nothing to do with React. Do not add irrelevant tags to questions, please.

Comment: If you have your _own_ logic to change the forms without navigating to a different page - then you will have to implement your _own_ logic for this as well.

Comment: @H.B. If the user is using React, and more specifically, React Router, I would say that is very much relevant to the question. They didn't add a [beforeunload] tag, they added the [reactjs] tag.

Comment: @HereticMonkey: There is no mention of any router, the question only states that Svelte is used.

Comment: Did you see my first comment? Where I asked about React? I was awaiting confirmation of whether or not the user was utilizing React, because they had added the [reactjs] tag. Don't edit questions just because you don't want to deal with a technology... Give users time to hash things out in comments. Now that the OP has removed the tag, I know it's not relevant.

Comment: @HereticMonkey: I waited for the author's response, which to me sounded like a confirmation that this does not involve React. This has nothing to do with me not wanting to deal with something, it's about keeping things clean and preventing unnecessary confusion. (PS, if you do not use `@`, the comment counts as being addressed to the post author and there will be no notification)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Whether there was a navigation or not is irrelevant, you just have to react to changes, e.g. you can handle a `change` event on the `form`-level to add the `beforeunload` handler which adds the confirmation question.

Something like:

```html
<script>
  function onChange() {
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', e => {
      e.preventDefault()
      return e.returnValue = "Are you sure you want to exit?";
    });
  }
</script>

<form on:change={onChange}>
  ...
</form>
```

(Maybe add a flag & `if` to prevent adding duplicate listeners.)

The `change` event only captures common interactions with native input elements. If the event is stopped from reaching the form (or whatever container you add the listener on) this will not work. It will also not capture more complex logic, like adding an item to some list.

Depending on your concrete code, you may need to handle additional/different events or changes.

If you use a client-side router of some kind you also have to signal to it, that it should not navigate away because `beforeunload` will not be triggered. How this is done depends entirely on the router being used.